# VS Debugger shows no local variables while debugging

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, pylance

VS Studio, Django etc all most recent versions.
The Debugger does not show any local variables while debugging.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def calculate():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    return x

def say_hello(request):
    x = calculate()
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'name': 'Sir Pickles'})
```

Comment: The warning likely says that you define `x` and `y`, but never *use* these variables in the rest of the function...

Comment: I updated it, regardless, VS debugger shows NO local variables while debugging